# copy azure blob files to azure synapse using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

My source files are in azure blob storage in CSV format.

I want these files unzipped & move to Azure synapse using ADF. In the copy activity source, I have given the input for the blob storage and in sink I have given the input for the synapse.
But I am not sure which copy method I need to choose in Polybase or Copy Command (Preview) or Bulk insert .
I tried with Polybase and Bulk insert copy methods. But I got the below error when running the pipeline.

```
ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error happened when loading data into SQL Data Warehouse.,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,
Message=User does not have permission to perform this action.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,
SqlErrorNumber=15247,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=15247,State=1,Message=User does not have permission to perform this action.,},],'
```

But in Azure sql Datawarehouse, I can able to insert the data using sql scripts.So, I believe above User Permission Error is not the issue to fail me pipeline.

Can you guide me please , as I am very new to Azure?

Thanks

Comment: IIRC you provide credentials to connect while setting up the datasource/sink. Use that credential to ensure it has write access to the right schema/table.

Comment: PS: It's (harder but) a LOT cheaper to create your own orchestration to use COPY command to load csv files into Synapse instead of Data factory.

Comment: Do you use the same user/account to connect to the Azure synapse?

Comment: Thanks Kashyap for the reply. Can you give more info for the orchestration way please ?

Comment: Hi Guys.. Thank you much for your ans. But the issue is in the firewall settings of the DB.It is fixed now and I am able to copy the file to dw.

Comment: Hi @GowriShankar, you're welcome! Sorry for the late response. I help you post it as answer and others can know your issue is resolved now. Hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the database firewall settings.

We are glad to hear that it's fixed now.